# Test lists to see if they are a prefix or suffix of another list

Tags: list, prolog, prefix, dcg

I'm stuck on a problem. I was wondering if I could get some help.

> Design a predicate bookends/3 that tests if the first list argument is
>   a prefix of the third and the second is a suffix of the third. Note that
>   the lists in the first and second arguments may overlap.
>
> Example Output

```
?-bookends([1],[3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]).
true.

?-bookends([],[4],[1,2,3,4]).
true.

?-bookends([1,2,3],[3,4],[1,2,3,4]).
true.

?-bookends([1],[2,3],[1,2,3,4]).
false.
```

What I have so far

```
suffix(Suffix,Suffix).
prefix([_|L],Suffix):- suffix(L,Suffix).
bookends([],[],[]).
bookends([X|L],[X|L1],[X|L2]):-
    prefix(L,L2),
    suffix(L1,L2).
```

How do I get suffix to work, or am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: Should `bookends([1,2,3],[3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]).` be true or false? If you allow overlap like this, then you could use `bookends(A, B, C) :- append(A, _, C), append(_, B, C).`

Comment: @mbratch: Very slick. (just an up vote didn't do it justice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let prefix & suffix do all the work:

```
bookends(A,B,C) :- prefix(A,C), suffix(B,C).
```

An empty list is always a prefix of anything:

```
prefix([],_).
```

If they share the same first element, check the rest

```
prefix([A|B],[A|C]) :- prefix(B,C).
```

You might need to write reverse:

```
suffix(A,B) :- reverse(A,AR), reverse(B,BR), prefix(AR,BR).
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was stuck on writing my own suffix.

Answer (score 1):

```
bookends(A, B, C) :-
   phrase((seq(A),...), C),
   phrase((...,seq(B)), C).

bookends_optimized(A, B, C) :-  % OK if C is a list
   phrase(seq(A), C,_),
   phrase(..., C,B).

bookends_no_overlap(A, B, C) :-
   phrase((seq(A),...,seq(B)), C).

seq([]) --> [].
seq([E|Es]) --> [E], seq(Es).

... --> [] | [_], ... .
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd point out that append works as suffix

```
append(_, Suffix, Something)
```

succeeds when Suffix is the suffix of something

```
append(Prefix, _, Something)
```

succeeds when Prefix is the prefix of something

```
bookends(Pre, Suff, X) :-
     append(Pre, _, X),
     append(_, Suff, X).
```

there's a list_append, append/2

```
bookends(Pre, Suff, X) :-  append([Pre, _, Suff], X).
```

that actually expresses intent best