# Suffix of a list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to define a predicate `suffix (S,L)` which holds if `S` is a list which is a suffix of
list `L`. For exemple:

```
?− suffix([a,b,c],[b,c]).
true.

?− suffix([a,b,c],[b,a]).
false.
```

I tried using `suffix(S,L):-  append(_,S,L).` but this won't work with my examples, shown above.

Comment: Some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038838/test-lists-to-see-if-they-are-a-prefix-or-suffix-of-another-list) may be relevant.

Comment: yes i've seen them, tested them. Prefix works fine, but suffix doesn't work properly with my examples. It always returns false

Comment: What do you mean by suffix? It seems you have the arguments exchanged in the first example, and the second one is no suffix at all.

Comment: Infirst example [b, c] is a suffix list of list [a, b, c].
In the second one, [b, a] is not a suffix for the list.

Comment: You have your arguments in the wrong order. Instead of `suffix(S,L):-  append(_,S,L).` try this: `suffix(S,L):-  append(_,L,S).`

Comment: yes, apparently that was the problem, missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works (see https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/gMgNaCKQ.pl for a working example):

```
suffix(L,S) :- append(_,S,L).
```

This also works (see https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/XqCXArvz.pl for a working example):

```
suffix(    L  , L ) .                % every list is a suffix of itself, with the empty list [] as its prefix
suffix( [_|L] , S ) :- suffix(L,S) . % otherwise, pop the list and try again.
```